# looping over records with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Customer model that has the attribute private. This attribute is only visible for a total of 3 users in the database. If this method (check_box) gets checked by one of those 3 users the Customer is only visible by them.

I'm currently looping over all of the Customers like this:

```
<% @customers.where(:private => false).each do |single_customer| %>
```

My question is how can I accomplish when one of the 3 users is signed in that `:private => false` gets changed to `@customers.each do |single_customer|` because then I don't want to filter the private attribute anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change the build up of the loop. This snippet is a bit of meta programming, but you can do it like this:

```
# in the controller for example.
@customers = Customer.where(private: false)
@customers = Customer.all if current_user.is_my_special_user?
```

In the view you then simply do this: `<% @customers.find_each do |customer| %>`

- use `find_each` for better performance if your collection is huge.
- by default you use the `private: false`
- if you detect your user is logged  in, you overwrite the `@customers`

Comment: I do not know if he has a `current_user` method defined, nor the logic in his class. So the meta programming refers to the methods used.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Instead of `@customers = Customers..` it should be `Customer`. Accepted the answer.

Comment: here is nothing about meta-programming. _Metaprogramming is a technique by which you can write code that writes code by itself dynamically at runtime. This means you can define methods and classes during runtime._